# How to assign File path to variable in c++

Tags: c++

I have a program which calculates md5 hash.
I can enter the text and it will generate the md5 code.
I want to get files from computer, for example text file and generate md5 for that. The problem is that i don't know how to get the file location and assign it to variable so i can put that variable in md5 generator function.

```
cout << "md5 of 'grape': " << md5("example") << endl;
```

as you can see in the above code i enter the md5 function argument which is "example" string, so i want something like this

```
string foo = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\1.txt";   
cout << "md5 of 'grape': " << md5(foo) << endl;
```

so this will calculate md5 for "C:\Users\User\Downloads\1.txt" string, but i want to calculate the 1.txt file's md5.

Comment: You have the file location (path) in `foo`. What else do you want? File location of what?

Comment: I think OP's looking for a way to get the current file path.

Comment: Perhaps the `md5` function expects a C-style string (`const char*`). If so, you can get one from the C++ string with `md5(foo.c_str())`.

Comment: You already have the file path in `foo`. Simply open the file using that path, then read the file's data into a `string`, and then pass that `string` to `md5()`. There are several questions on StackOverflow that explain how to read a file into a `string`. Or better, have `md5()` take a file path as input so it can open and read the file directly, in small chunks to minimize memory usage.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but what if the file us not only a text  file, it can be picture, video, or even code of php or js. then how can i do that?

Comment: Read the raw bytes as if it was a binary file and convert it into a string somehow?

Comment: @SchiSchun The MD5 algorithm operates on bytes, not on string characters. However, since a `std::string` holds byte-sized characters, it can hold the raw bytes for any kind of binary file without needing to convert anything. Or, like I said, you could change the `md5()` function to read raw bytes directly from the file instead. Or maybe, from a `std::istream`, then you can choose what kind of input to hash (string, file, etc)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by reading the whole file into a string and passing it to md5 function like this (I assume you are using [zedwood's md5](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "md5.h"

int main()
{
    MD5 md5;
    std::ifstream ifs("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\1.txt", std::ios::binary);
    if (ifs)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << ifs.rdbuf();
        std::string s(oss.str());
        md5.update(s.data(), s.size());
        md5.finalize();
        std::cout << md5.hexdigest() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This should work with non-text files too.

Comment: If you use .c_str() before the call to md5(), you'll drop everything after the first byte with value 0.

Comment: @Jeffrey changed

Comment: You should call `oss.str()` only once and cache the result, eg: `std::string s = oss.str(); md5.update(s.data(), s.size());`